# How to clear int[] array in android?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, sum

I have an example that calculates total expense and income. There are some values in integer array that converted from a string array. Once I am running the code the sum is 6000 and running again the same code the sum gets multiplied to 12000. How can I override this problem. Please check my code given below..

```
public static int incSum=0;

int[] numbersinc = new int[theAmount.length];

    for(int i=0;i<theAmount.length;i++)
    {

        numbersinc[i]=Integer.parseInt(theAmount[i]);

        incSum=incSum+numbersinc[i];
    }

    Log.e("SUM INC","Sum Inc= "+incSum);    <<<<<- This sum is multiplying
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a complete code snippet and is more relevant as a java question rather than android.

Comment: It looks like your issue is more to do with the sum not being reset rather than an issue with arrays. Reset the incSum = 0 before each run over the array (that is, before the for loop).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply assign `null` to the reference. (This will work for any type of array, not just `ints`)

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
arr = null;
```

This will 'clear out' the array.  You can also assign a new array to that reference if you like:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
arr = new int[]{6, 7, 8, 9};
```

If you are worried about memory leaks, don't be.  The garbage collector will clean up any references left by the array.

Another example:

```
float[] arr = ;// some array that you want to clear
arr = new float[arr.length];
```

This will create a new `float[]` initialized to the default value for float.

So in your code try this:

```
public int incSum=0;

int[] numbersinc = new int[theAmount.length];
incSum = 0; //add this line
    for(int i=0;i<theAmount.length;i++)
    {

        numbersinc[i]=Integer.parseInt(theAmount[i]);

        incSum=incSum+numbersinc[i];
    }

    Log.e("SUM INC","Sum Inc= "+incSum);    <<<<<- This sum is multiplying
  numbersinc = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int incSum=0;
```

your variable is `static` so when you run again then previous value store in `incSum` variable  .

Remove `static` from `incSum`